# Help identifying which controller is currently in use

Tags: magento-1.7, controllers

I've been asked to make a couple of seemingly simple changes to a Magento (version 1.7.0.2) admin page however I'm brand new to Magento and a bit bewildered. I can identify the controller that is responsible for the page that I need to change and I can make simple changes to the text and add variables to display (using $GLOBALS in the controller - is this bad practice?). That's about all I think I need to do.

The page I need to change is:

```
www.mywebsite.com/index.php/admin/sales_invoice/view/invoice_id/1559/key/1dsdfuy9etc/
```

And the relevant controller file is app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php

The following page I cannot track down so well:

```
www.mywebsite.com/index.php/webforms/adminhtml_webforms/index/key/9313313cd8etc/
```

How do I track down this controller? I want to find out how this page gets it's data and then try and add one or two bits of it to the first page. I've ran find / -type d -name webforms via ssh and it turned up the following results (which don't seem to reveal what controller is controlling the page):

/home/die/public_html/app/locale/ru_RU/template/email/webforms
/home/die/public_html/app/locale/fi_FI/template/email/webforms
/home/die/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/webforms
/home/die/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/webforms
/home/die/public_html/skin/frontend/base/default/webforms

Any pointers welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find here:

```
app/code/community/VladimirPopov/WebForms/controllers/Adminhtml/WebformsController.php
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @techguy4web this looks like the right path! Now to make sense of it...

Comment: vote-up also appreciated ;)

Comment: I'm not allowed up-vote, I'm not reputable enough yet